# Get calendar [public vs private] value from Google Calendar API

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api, acl, google-apps

I'm trying to figure out how the Google Calendars API works, so far I've connected to everything without an issue and its returning results as expected.

What I'd ideally like to do is use calendarList (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) to get a list of the user's calendars and display information about whether they are set to PUBLIC, e.g. have this boxed checked.

[image]

But from everything I've looked at through the api, this isn't something that can be done

Just wondering if anyone sees anything to the contrary or if anyone's come across the problem before. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in all of the documents about Calendar API but like you said, I can't see any documents that can do or make what you want.

You can only use [CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) to add and remove existing calendars to/from the users’ list. You also use it to retrieve and set the values of user-specific calendar properties, such as default reminders. Another example is foreground color, since different users can have different colors set for the same calendar.

Comment: Thanks for checking with me, appreciate the research